# DropzoneJs Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js

> Before I start to explain my issue I have to say I read lots of topics
>   in this site and most of their issue was about `enctype` but my form
>   is included that.

## Issue

I can upload my photos `at least in dropzone box view` i don't get error. but as soon as I click save button I will get

```
"Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null"
```

here is my `form`

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'dropzone.store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone')) }}
             <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
             </div>
             <input name="imageable_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}" />

             <div class="clearfix"></div>
             {{ Form::submit('Create Product', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
            {{Form::close()}}
```

my `controller`

```
public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
  {
    $productID = $request->imageable_id;
    $product = Product::findOrFail($productID);
    // works
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $filename = 'product' . '-' . str_random(10) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filePath = public_path('images/');
    $request->file('file')->move($filePath, $filename);


     return Image::create([
      'name' => $filename,
      'imageable_id' => $productID,
    ]);

  }
```

PS: error comes from `$filename = 'product' . '-' . str_random(10) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();`

my result `on success` in `console`:

```
{"name":"product-oQPyBfyZDK.jpg","imageable_id":"3","updated_at":"2018-02-07 16:30:17","created_at":"2018-02-07 16:30:17","id":13}
```

## UPDATE

I put my `controller` code in if statement like:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $filename = 'product' . '-' . str_random(10) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('file')->move($filePath, $filename);
    }
```

and now i get this error:

> Undefined variable: filename

which is in:

```
return Image::create([
      'name' => $filename,
      'imageable_id' => $productID,
    ]);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

i put my return inside if and it working, look at my update part for more information.